# Java / startsWith more than one letter?

Tags: java, if-statement, startswith

I am still working on a Project with Java and wanted to ask if someone could help me ?

I am asking me if it's possible to check a string with more than one Letter with "startsWith"?

like:

```
 if (string Alpha.startsWith("a"||"A"||"b"||"B"||"c"||"C"||"d"||"D")){
                        System.out.println("Wrong!");
                        System.out.println("\n");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Wrong Key!");
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: Can you use a Regular Expression?

Comment: try http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char first = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(0));
if (first >= 'a' && first <= 'd')
{
    // etc.
}
```

If you want to avoid possible [locale issues](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/character_tolowercase.htm), you can give two ranges, one for lower case and one for upper case:

```
char first = str.charAt(0);
if ((first >= 'a' && first <= 'd')
    || (first >= 'A' && first <= 'D'))
{
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I would've said.

Comment: Question was about `Java`, not `C` ?

Comment: @GyroGearless Thanks, updated the syntax accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I would put this in new method:

```
private boolean myStartsWith(String... args) {
   for(String str : args) {
       if(args.startsWith(str) {
          return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

And then use it:

```
str.myStartsWith(new String[]{"a","b","c"});
```

Comment: @KevinBowersox Easily by passing it to the String array. Or using `toLowerCase` or whatever.. I'm just giving him a direction.

Comment: Use it with `str.myStartsWith("a", "b", "c");` instead. You have declared a vararg so try using it too.

Comment: @maba Indeed, I edited it after it was `String[] args`.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, this is clearly the case where regular expressions should be used:

```
java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^[a-cA-C]");
java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(alpha);  //
if (m.matches()) {
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this

```
str.matches("^[A-Da-d].+");
```

Comment: Ìf you want to match from the start of the string, you have to prepend a "^" on the regex, otherwise any string with some letter inside matches!

Comment: And i should have tried this before commenting, see my followup on lyaffes answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
String str = "ABCDEF";
if(str.matches("(a|A|b|B|c|C|d|D).*")) {
   ...
};
```

Comment: Ìf you want to match from the start of the string, you have to prepend a "^" on the regex, otherwise any string with some letter inside matches!

Comment: I don't think so, please provide an example string for which my code works provides incorrect match.

Comment: Argh, you are right, i was thinking in Perl when i wrote this comment! In Perl, matching say `$mystery = "@#++**+::,.,ABCDEF";` against `if ($mystery =~ m/(a|A|b|B|c|C|d|D).*/) ...` would match the A in the middle, obviously this is not true in Java! Can you please make some edit to your post so i may change my vote?

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
if (Alpha.startsWith("a") || Alpha.startsWith("A") || // and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean startsWith(String value, String[] chars){
    for(String check:chars){
        if(value.indexOf(check) == 0 || value.indexOf(check.toUpperCase()) == 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Usage**

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String val1 = "A string";
        String val2 = "a string";
        String val3 = "x string";
        String[] chars = {"a","b","c","d"};

        System.out.println(startsWith(val1,chars));
        System.out.println(startsWith(val2,chars));
        System.out.println(startsWith(val3,chars));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this:

```
    String str = "Alpha";
    String[] tar = "aAbBcCdD".split("");
    for(String s: tar) {
        if(str.startsWith(s)){
        ...your own logic
        }
    }
```